# Angular how to have div show on load but also have fading transition

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to have one of the red colored divs show by default on page load. Right now, it is not showing until you click the button "topred".

http://plnkr.co/edit/3dZIRgLISiC1s4wYVL4z?p=preview

If you click the "topred" button once after the page loads. That is how I would like it to look. I have tried adding a new class to the red div, but then I end of losing the fade transition effect when I click the button a second time.

```
.templatez {
-webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
font-size: 40px;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 0px;
color: #ffffff;
}


.templatez.top {
 z-index: 3;
 background-color: red;
opacity: 1;
}

.templatez.middle {
 z-index:2;
 background-color: orange;
}

.templatez.bottom {
 z-index:1;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your variables accordingly, either directly via JavaScript or e.g. by using the ngInit directive:

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate" ng-init="myVar1='top';myVar2='';myVar3=''">
```

However, please note that your code snippet needs serious improvement as for example the solution using the myVar1, myVar2 and myVar3 variables seems terrible from an engineering perspective.

Comment: But I started with the code form here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass How can that need serious improvement if it is straight from the api.

Comment: Because it is an example to show some technology, not for production code. Also, because they did use separate variables to add new elements, whereas your three variables are actually one, because there is just one state (i.e. just one box should be visible at one point in time)

Comment: I'm still going to use this code as it is because I don't know how to improve it. I will change the var to something else. Thanks for your help.